# Service fabric endpoint port configuration

Tags: c#, azure, configuration, azure-service-fabric

I want to deploy multiple instances of service fabric application to one service fabric cluster. In order to do it I need to have ability to configure port in service manifest (so different instances are running on different port). Every example which i seen use 'hardcoded' value in this file. Is it possible to have it configured in ApplicationParameters or in Settings.xml file ?

Another option which I consider is to use tokenization to solve my problem (so i have token in service manifest, which will be replaced by tokenization task during VSTS deployment). But in that case I don't have simple way to run service locally in Visual Studio (or maybe I have ? I will also appreciate suggestions how to do it).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to specify the port at all? If you leave it blank in the ServiceManifest then it will use a random port. You can then use the Service Fabric naming service to ask it what the port is for a specific instance of a service is.

Comment: I have to know on which port my services are running because i want to have possibility to access it from the internet. (it is REST service)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override the port. If you do not care about a particular port, leave it blank or set to 0. We are working on allowing to override the port.

Comment: Do you know when this feature will be available ?